# How to apply filter to the request to resource which are directly under webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, filter

I want to apply filter in below URL's.
http://10.78.97.29/robots.txt
http://10.78.97.29/sitemap.xml
https://10.78.97.29/

Since they does not contain any specific URL pattern , I am not getting any idea. And in which web.xml I have to add that filter mapping. I am using Tomcat as a webcontainer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat by default uses the web application named `ROOT` to serve the application at the root folder of the server. You can either handle the requests there or just have the files contained in the web application.

You might want to read about [tomcat naming](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) for more details, explaining this behaviour.

Alternatively, you can also have an Apache httpd in front of your tomcat and handle those files there.